# Calculate Hurst Exponent on Raster stack In R

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I have a stack of five maps showing average NDVI values, and I want to calculate the Hurst exponent for each pixel in the stack using the "hurstexp" function from the "pracma" package. My stacked maps have some missing values (NAs) represented as -Inf when extracted, and I want to return an output raster with the calculated Hurst exponent values. Can you please help me with this, including how to handle the NAs in the process?

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(pracma)

modis_list <- list.files(path = "path",
                         pattern = "*.tif$", full.names = TRUE)
modis_raster <- stack(modis_list)

# i try this but not working
modis_hurst <- raster::calc(modis_raster, function(x) {
  spec <- hurstexp(x, d = 50, display = TRUE)
  return(spec$H)
})


writeRaster(modis_hurst, filename = "path/to/output/file.tif", format = "GTiff")


Error:Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
  cannot use this function
```

```
#### I also tried this
calculate_hurst <- function(x) {
  tryCatch({
    spec <- hurstexp(x, d = 50, display = FALSE)  # Use display = FALSE to suppress plot
    return(as.numeric(spec$H))  # Ensure the result is numeric
  }, error = function(e) {
    return(NA)  # Handle NA values or errors during calculation
  })
}
# Calculate the Hurst exponent for each layer using calc
modis_hurst <- raster::calc(modis_raster, calculate_hurst)

# Write the result to a new raster file
writeRaster(modis_hurst, filename = "path/to/output/file.tif", format = "GTiff")


Error in setValues(out, x) : values must be numeric, logical or factor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `app` in the `terra` package (i.e., the new `raster` package). Since I don't know the function `hurstexp` and its results meaning, I suppose that whenever a pixel in your time series is NA, the results should be NA (but this is up to you). In any case, `hurstexp` cannot handle NA, so you have to get rid of them.

```
library(terra)
library(pracma)

f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
#create raster stack
rr <- c(r,r*2,r/2,r^2,log(r))
plot(rr)

spec <- terra::app(rr,function(x){
  x <- as.numeric(x)
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  if(length(x)==0)return(NA)
  spec <- hurstexp(x,display = F)
  Hs <- as.numeric(spec$Hs)
  return(Hs)
},cores=1)

plot(spec)
```

If you (likely) have more than 1 core in your machine you can change the `cores` argument of `app` to speed up the computation by running the function in parallel.

**EDIT**

The problem with returning more than one parameter in `hutstexp` is that `app` cannot return a raster stack. So, one solution could be to loop over the desired parameters with e.g. `lapply`.

```
res <- lapply(list("Hs","He"),function(par){
  spec <- terra::app(rr,function(x){
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    if(length(x)==0)return(NA)
    spec <- hurstexp(x,display = F)
    res <- spec[[par]]
    return(res)
  },cores=1)
})

res <- do.call(c,res)
plot(res)
```

Maybe there are better ways, but an advantage of this approach is that you can parallelize both the function in `app` with the argument `cores` and the outer `lapply` loop, with e.g., `foreach` or `snowfall` (but all other parallelization mechanisms should work fine)

Comment: Thank you so much. @Elia. I really appreciate your help. Stay blessed

Comment: I also want to ask the function will only calculate HS or other parameters' as well.

Comment: See the new EDIT

Comment: Thanks for your time, I got it....................